# Visual Studio Community 2015 won't start

Tags: visual-studio, devenv

When I try to start it. The loading screen flash by in 1 millisecond then dissapear. Iv'e tried the `devenv.exe /Setup` solution, but devenv.exe won't start either.

Don't know what to do! I think it has something with to do with devenv.exe. Because after I used the selector, it has been corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already tried the basics (turning it off and turning it back on again, etc.), you may want to try running it as administrator. **Right-click>Run As Administrator**

I've had some issues on and off with VS not always working for me unless I run as admin.

If that fails, you can repair the installation by going through the Programs and Features menu.

Comment: Second time I did a "repair" from installation it started working again!